# Repair EFI partion after accidental formating

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-partition, disk-formatting

I accidentally formatted my EFI partition so now the system won't boot. I am a complete novice in this. I did some research about this issue on the internet but no positive results so far(basically because of having limited idea about what is going on).

I've tried the accepted answer from here [How can I reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition)
But I am stuck on the `sudo chroot /mnt`

It returns me an error;

```
failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

[terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKCOI.png)

[fdisk -l output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCqG.png)

Would appreciate any help, especially any detailed and step-by-step solution because, as I said, I'm totally new here. Data recovery is not necessary since anyways I wanted to format it, I just want the system to work again.

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: can you give output from the rest of the commands? By the way, if you wanted to reinstall the whole system you can just "install Ubuntu" using a live USB and use the whole disk. It will erase and rewrite everything like new (including partitioning and such)

Comment: @Esther updated the descriptions with some screenshots.
I also tried to reinstall ubuntu several times but the whole process just freezed

Comment: The easiest method would be re-installing Ubuntu. What exactly did you mean by "the whole process just freezed". In which phase does that happen exactly? Try creating bootable disk again using Rufus if possible and select GPT partition before starting the process.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu I have Ubuntu on both of my laptops and it looks like Rufus is only available for Windows. I used instead BalenaEtcher, is it ok? Also, when I try to install Ubuntu the process is stuck Detecting file systems, as I can see in the terminal it returns "Source ID was not found when attempting to remove it" in a loop (it's alrealdy benn 1 hour". The sceenshot https://photos.app.goo.gl/EwwZUSe74Nw4pzfZ7

Comment: Instead of clicking on **Install Ubuntu** click on **Try Ubuntu** and open GParted and kindly upload a screenshot of GParted window.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu here is the screenshot of GParted https://photos.app.goo.gl/G111vg3iY4Mse5nw6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reinstall Ubuntu, the command provided in this answer fixed the problem https://askubuntu.com/a/440736/1628406